# Pagination in React with fetch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pagination

I am fetching objects from an API simply with

```
getData() {
    fetch('API_URL').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
        this.setState({ jobs: data.jobs });
    }).catch(console.log);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
}
```

But I want to be able to click a button to load more objects.

I guess that I should create the API such that it only prints e.g. 10 objects at a time and keeps a variable "pageNumber" and if I click the "load more" button, it should fetch from next page and append the new objects.

Is this the right approach? Or can I simply load thousands of objects when mounting the component and use React to limit how many are seen? I guess this would be a very inefficient way to fetch the data, but I am not really sure how well React handles this.

Can I, for instance, in my API just keep print X number of objects and in my fetch request decide how many objects are loaded? So when I have pressed "load more" 2 times, the API endpoint will return 30 objects instead of only 10 - even though the first 20 have already been fetched before?

I have tried searching for pagination in React, but I only get a lot of pagination libraries. I just want to understand the very basic initial fetching and the fetching following clicking load more.

## Edit

But if I have an API endpoint which returns something like

```
{
  page: 1,
  objectsPerPage: 10,
  numPages: 30,
  objects: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

and I am initially retrieving the objects on page 1, and every time I click "Load more", I increase the page number and append the objects on the next page (with `this.setState({ jobs: this.state.jobs.concat(data.jobs) });` where `data.jobs` is the list of objects on the next page, then I would be afraid that new objects are created in the database, so which objects belong to which page is completely screwed up and not all or some duplicates are shown.

Comment: "Or can I simply load thousands of objects when mounting the component and use React to limit how many are seen?" - that's sort of faking pagination. Can your api request return a limited set of results?

Comment: Yes. I am making the API myself, so I can limit the number of objects and I can add fields to the API endpoint such as "currentPage", "numObjects", "totalNumObjects", etc. to determine whether I have loaded all objects. I am quite new in React, so I am just guessing how it should be done. I hope I'm somehow on the right track.

Comment: Hi, I'm now on the same situation, except I can't manipulate the API because it's already done. What was your solution? @Jamgreen

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the right approach to have a pageNumber on the API, so you only look for the registers you don't have.

On the other size if your data is not too big you can make the fake pagination having all the objects in memory and only showing the ones that you are interested in.

I don't recommend to increase the number of objects you are looking for because you are not getting the advantage of the ones you have already fetched and everytime you increase the number, the request will last more and more.